# Internet Explorer tile does not open application

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Girlfriends dad called me with not being able to open Internet Explorer so I did the following debugging via Remote Desktop.

Clicking on the tile sends to desktop and Internet Explorer is not opened (not even in Task Manager).

Upon searching for "Internet Explorer" a single application tile is shown with the IE logo and the text "ms-resource:TileDisplayName".

I got round this by pinning `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` to Start and Desktop which is a good enough work-round but I am interested as to why this would have occurred and how one would go about repairing this...

Comment: I would just use the system reset feature to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut must have been corrupted somehow. Making a new shortcut as you did is a perfectly good solution.